# Why do Higgs decays depend on the production method?

Tags: particle-physics, higgs, large-hadron-collider, tevatron

I'm reading about Higgs phenomenology and I have come across the following table.
[image: higgs decay]
I don't see why gluon fusion to $b \bar{b}$ is considered to be "impossible" in this table.

As far as I can tell, all Higgs of a given energy are the same after production, so the allowed decays ought to be independent of the production method.

Comment: What's the source? I'd like to see the caption and text surrounding the table. I suspect it means impossible to observe at that collider, not impossible to occur

Comment: I have it from slides used in a lecture. There is nothing more written on the page but I think it looks like it was taken from elsewhere initially. I'll have a look around and see if I can find the origin of it.

Comment: @Kris If it's available online, a link here would be helpful for us; if it's from a course you're taking, your instructor should be able to help you out.

Comment: Particle decay modes are completely independent of their production mechanisms. These ratings are based on the product of cross section and branching ratio for each process. They express how well each experiment can detect them.

Comment: @dukwon surely that's only true in the NWA in which $\sigma(ii\to h \to ff) = \sigma(ii\to H) \times BR(h\to ff)$

Comment: There are, in general, spin correlations and off-shell effects (though the former are absent for scalars).